# How to understand degeneracy and singularity of field

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge-theory, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In the online lecure given by Professor Wu Yongshi https://www.koushare.com/video/videodetail/4619 1:30‘, he says:

> Suppose we have a state $|m,R(t)\rangle$, where $R(t)$ is controlled parameters adiabaticlly changed over time. If $R(T)=R(0)$, then we'll obtain Berry's phase $\oint_{c} A^{mm}_{\mu}dR^{\mu}=\int\int_{s}F^{mm}_{\mu\nu}dR^{\mu}\wedge dR^{\nu}$. When $|m,R(t)\rangle$ and another state $|n,R(t)\rangle$, $F$ would be divergent.

I couldn't figure out why $F$ is divergent.Could anyone help?